# "How to Split an interval in two part interval_left and interval_right "?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame with column interval (for example [2,5], [3,8]...), I want to add in my data two columns (split between an interval_left column and interval_right column), that interval_left take 2,3 and interval_right to take 5,8

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to have a look 
at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking a question here. You probably should include some code with your question to help us understand your issue.

Comment: Any one have idea please ? Thank you.

Comment: As I said, it's difficult to help you with any code. What did you try? What doesn't work?

Comment: I don't have a code, I want to split a column timestamp in my data (like this [2019-05-09 00:01:25, 2019-05-09 00:06:25]) between two new columns in my data ( interval_left that takes 2019-05-09 00:01:25 and interval_right that takes 2019-05-09 00:06:25 ), I hope it's clear